# MutationObserver menu/hover

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have main-menu (`"#head-menu .container ul"`) and need to add one more element with 2 links (links should show when clicked on Element, and hover when clicked again). But, when i try to prepend my Element by using this code:

```
($("#head-menu .container ul").prepend('
    <li class="main-menu-doc">
       <span><a href="#">Инструкция по заказам</a></span>
    </li>');
)
```

Element is added twice, and I don't know why.
And my question is how to add my little menu with 2 links?

Here is my code about it:

```
function flatten(arr) {
    return [].concat(...arr);
}

function add() {
    var ar = [];
    [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.modern-table.order-products > tbody > tr.order-product'), function(tr) {
        $(tr).find('td.properties-td.nested-td_hide.bord.align-to-input').find(".additional.elipsis").each(function(k,v) {
            var span = $(v).text();
            b = span.replace( /\s/g, '');
            if (b.includes('банки')) {
                t = b.replace('банки', 'банки:');
                var myarr = t.split(":");
                var arr = myarr[1].split(';');
                ar.push(arr);
            }
        });
    });
    var unique = find_duplicate_in_array(flatten(ar));
    if(unique != null) {
        $("#intaro_crmbundle_ordertype_customFields_bank_payment").val(unique.toString());
    }
}

function find_duplicate_in_array(arra1) {
    var object = {};
    var result = [];

    arra1.forEach(function (item) {
        if(!object[item])
            object[item] = 0;
        object[item] += 1;
    })

    for (var prop in object) {
        if(object[prop] >= 2) {
            result.push(prop);
        }
    }

    return result;

}

function getInfo() {

}
var dom_observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {


    $('#intaro_crmbundle_ordertype_customFields_bank_payment').on('click', function() {
        add();
    });
    $('#intaro_crmbundle_ordertype_deliveryType_chosen').on('click', function() {
        $('#intaro_crmbundle_ordertype_deliveryType_chosen li').each(function(n, elem) {
            $(elem).show();
        });

        var endPayments = [];
        var obj  = {};
        var count = document.querySelectorAll('.modern-table.order-products > tbody > tr.order-product').length;
        [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.modern-table.order-products > tbody > tr.order-product'), function(tr) {
            $(tr).find('td.properties-td.nested-td_hide.bord.align-to-input').find(".additional.elipsis").each(function(k,v) {
                var span = $(v).text();
                b = span.replace( /\s/g, '');
                if (b in obj) {
                    obj[b] += 1;
                }
                else {
                    obj[b] = 1;
                }
            });
        });
        Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (key){
            if(obj[key] == count) {
                endPayments.push(key);
            }
        })


        if(endPayments.includes('доставкиДоставкакурьером;')) {
            $('#intaro_crmbundle_ordertype_deliveryType_chosen').find('li[data-option-array-index="0"]').hide();
            $('#intaro_crmbundle_ordertype_deliveryType_chosen').find('li[data-option-array-index="2"]').hide();
        }
        if(endPayments.includes('доставкиСамовывоз;')) {
            $('#intaro_crmbundle_ordertype_deliveryType_chosen').find('li[data-option-array-index="1"]').hide();
        }
    });
    $('.add-payment-type').on('click', function() {
        var allPayments = {
            'smartкарта3':'13',
            'магнит5':'5',
            'картаfun6':'54',
            'картапокупок6':['31', '27'],
            'картапокупок12':['60', '32'],
            'картапокупок18':['29', '61'],
            'картачерепаха10':'50',
            'халва3':['18', '22'],
            'халва5':['23', '56'],
            'халва8':['25', '21'],
            'халва12':['52', '59']
        };
        $('ul[data-new-index=1] li').each(function(n, elem) {
            $(elem).show();
        });

        var endPayments = [];
        var obj  = {};
        var count = document.querySelectorAll('.modern-table.order-products > tbody > tr.order-product').length;
        [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.modern-table.order-products > tbody > tr.order-product'), function(tr) {
            $(tr).find('td.properties-td.nested-td_hide.bord.align-to-input').find(".additional.elipsis").each(function(k,v) {
                var span = $(v).text();
                b = span.replace( /\s/g, '');
                if (b in obj) {
                    obj[b] += 1;
                }
                else {
                    obj[b] = 1;
                }
            });
        });
        Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (key){
            if(obj[key] == count) {
                endPayments.push(key);
            }
        });

        if(count > 0) {
            endPayments.forEach(e => delete allPayments[e]);
            Object.keys(allPayments).forEach(function (k) {
                if(Array.isArray(allPayments[k])) {
                    for (val in allPayments[k]) {
                        $('ul[data-new-index=1]').find('li[data-type-id='+allPayments[k][val]+']').hide();
                    }
                } else {
                    $('ul[data-new-index=1]').find('li[data-type-id='+allPayments[k]+']').hide();
                }
            });
        }
    });
});

var dom_observer2 = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        if(mutation.target.id == "notification-box") {
            console.log(mutation);
        }
    });
});

var observer = new MutationObserver(function() {
    $("#head-menu .container ul").prepend('<li class="main-menu-doc" id="main-menu-doc""><span><a href="#">Инструкция по заказам</a></span></li>');
    $(".main-menu-doc").on('click', function() {
        var newItem = document.createElement('ul');
        // myFunction();
        this.append(newItem);
    });
    
});


var container = document.documentElement || document.body;
var container2 = document.documentElement || document.body;

var container3 = document.documentElement|| document.body;

var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true};
var config2 = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true, subtree: true};
var config3 = {childList: true, characterData: true, subtree: false};

dom_observer.observe(container, config);
dom_observer2.observe(container2, config2);
observer.observe(container3, config3);
```

Super sorry for huge code and my bad english :[

Here is how HTML code looks like:

```
<div id="head-menu">
   <div class="container">
     <ul>
        <li> </li>
        <li> </li>
        <li> </li>
     </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: add html and css in here

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov add html for example. Css havn't. This is self-written plugin, not by me.